# How can a drop from Swing into JavaFX WebView be handled by HTML5 DnD Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, swing, javafx, drag-and-drop

When dragging something from a Swing component (like JLabel for better control) I can't seem to find a way to have the drop handled by a HTML5 page in a JavaFX WebView. The WebView is inside a JFXPanel and is showing this page: http://html5demos.com/drag-anything

So the goal ist to have the drop handled by the Javascript of the page. The drag source in Swing has just the DataFlavor with mime-type 'text/plain'. It can't be dropped on the WebView, though drags from the WebView into a Swing drop component work fine. Of course on the WebView component the *setOnDragOver* and *setOnDragDropped* event handlers can be set, which works, but this way the drop never reaches the page in the view. Am I missing something here? Running Oracle JDK 1.8.0_51

I really think it should work like this, a workaround with capturing the events on the webview and injecting them into the html page with some custom javascript can't be the way to go.

Here's my little test code (imports simplified):

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    import javafx.*;

    import javax.swing.*;

    import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

    public class JfxDndTest implements DragGestureListener {

        public void initAndShowGUI() {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("WebView in JFXPanel");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
            fxPanel.setOpaque(false);
            fxPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

            JLabel label = new JLabel(" TEST DRAG ");
            label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
            label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 3));
            label.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler() {
                @Override
                public boolean canImport(JComponent comp, DataFlavor[] transferFlavors) {
                    System.out.println("can import? flavors: " + Arrays.asList(transferFlavors));
                    for (DataFlavor df : transferFlavors) {
                        if (df.getMimeType().startsWith("text/plain")) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return super.canImport(comp, transferFlavors);
                }
            });
            DragSource dragSource = DragSource.getDefaultDragSource();

            // Create a DragGestureRecognizer and
            // register as the listener
            dragSource.createDefaultDragGestureRecognizer(label, DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY, this);

            JLabel label2 = new JLabel(" TEST DROP ");
            label2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
            label2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 3));
            new DropTarget(label2, new DropTargetAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
                    dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY);
                    try {
                        InputStream is = (InputStream) dtde.getTransferable().getTransferData(new DataFlavor("text/plain"));
                        String s = IOUtils.toString(is);
                        System.out.println(s);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    dtde.dropComplete(true);
                }
            });

            frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            frame.getContentPane().add(fxPanel);
            frame.getContentPane().add(label);
            frame.getContentPane().add(label2);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);

            // Init JFX
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    initFX(fxPanel);
                }
            });
        }

        private void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {

            WebView webView = new WebView();
            webView.getEngine().setOnError(new EventHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handle(WebErrorEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: " + event.getMessage());
                }
            });
            webView.getEngine().load("http://html5demos.com/drag-anything");

            Scene scene = new Scene(webView, 800, 650);

            fxPanel.setScene(scene);
        }

        @Override
        public void dragGestureRecognized(DragGestureEvent dge) {
            dge.startDrag(null, new Transferable() {

                @Override
                public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
                    System.out.println("supports? " + flavor.getMimeType());
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
                    try {
                        return new DataFlavor[] { new DataFlavor("text/plain") };
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
                    System.out.println("getdata: " + flavor.getMimeType());
                    return IOUtils.toInputStream("TEST");
                }
            });
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new JfxDndTest().initAndShowGUI();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```